# Can Windows 10 Download as ISO using Media Creation Tool be resumed if failed?

Tags: windows, windows-10, iso-image

I downloaded Windows Media Creation tool from Microsoft Site in order to download Windows 10 Pro 64 as a separate ISO file to a local folder on my Vaio laptop running Windows 7 Starter 32 OEM.

Everything went fine until it reached 100%. Thereafter the Media Creation Tool app simply closed without doing anything and the ISO was not created. I again did a fresh download and the story repeated. At 100% completion the tool just closes without integrating the temp file into ISO.

I searched the net for any undocumented trick to resume the process, however the proposed solution (running setupprep.exe from C:\$Windows.~WS\Sources
) in my case was not possible, as no such file was found therein.

Is there any fix for this to somehow resume or complete the download process now?

For now I have left all the downloaded stuff under  C:\$Windows.~WS\Sources\ as it is, includes several .dll files and a .tmp file of around 3 GB.

Thanks.

Comment: why not just download the regular iso and run it from a cd or usb? it does pretty much the same thing as media creation tool

Comment: @Blaine - Is direct ISO download available from Microsoft? I wasn't aware somehow.

Comment: here you go https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Blaine stated in the comments, just download the ISO directly from MS.

If you're on Windows: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench

If you're on Linux/OSX: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO

Comment: You'll probably be redirected to the page for downloading the MCT if you're on Windows. Better this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench

Comment: I mean it redirects to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 once you visit it, unless you are on Linux or OS X or so.

Comment: Oh, I see. edited answer. I am on Ubuntu, so I guess I didn't get redirected.

Comment: Thank you all. I shall follow the given links and update you as well.

Comment: Not working anymore.